# How would getUserMedia be able to stream to a server (efficiently, anyway)?

Tags: javascript, html, voip

Currently, with getUserMedia I am able to use a blob URL in order to pipe the (audio) data right back. However, I'd like to be able to get raw data from it. Is the blob URL special "black magic" that is useless once the page is closed? Is there actual data encoded in it or just a pointer to some stream in memory? If I were to try to open this blob in another browser, will I succeed?

More so, what is the best way of taking the stream object, directly from getUserMedia, and send it's raw audio (I don't care about the socket code itself, but how would you just take a sample type thing)? I eventually want to play around with a minimalist VoIP-type app.

I'm currently using a code sample like this:

```
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true}, function(stream){
 console.log(window.URL.createObjectURL(stream));
}, function(){
    console.log("REJECTION!");
});
```

However, I'd like to be able to take the stream variable and actually get tangible data, something that another client would be able to parse and process.

Answer (score 1):

@bobbybee, as @konga-raju points in his answer to [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069551/how-to-submit-stream-video-from-browser-to-a-server), the implementation isn't ready on browsers yet.
However, you can try to come around it by recording video as webm (with a canvas trick) + audio (encoded to wav/mp3 with recorderjs) in separate tracks, pushing them to you server and compiling them back again. See [RecordJS for that](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC) and these [two](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/issues/8#issuecomment-19252169) [issues](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/issues/48). At the moment, it doesn't do AV together so you'd have to play around with it to make it happen.

Or you could just way a couple of weeks until it the record implementation lands in some version of Chrome. :)