# Send MediaStream from Browser to Server to encode

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc, http-live-streaming

I am developing a video conferencing system that should enable users to stream a session to (for now) the server. I would prefer using WebRTC to connect client and server. The big hurdle I stumbled upon now is the question how to actually "live stream" the video from getUserMedia to the server.
I came across various methods including using a canvas element as well as some gateway (like Janus or Kurento) in the middle. I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25686416) here on Stack Overflow. However since this is a learning project I would prefer to use a pure WebRTC solution as well as not using the upcoming recording API, since I am aiming at a "live streaming" to the server.

My idea was to use nodeJS and have the server act as a peer. However I did not found a package for nodeJS that would enable those two channels (dataChannel seems always to be possible and might be a solution together with the canvas solution). So my question now: Are there any packages out there that I missed? Or is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: See the discussion on this page and the second reply by Adam Roach: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.media/pos7woJMimo

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer - however I haven't found a way how do to it in NodeJS.

Comment: I got it to work sending Mediarecorder recordings over the data channel to NodeJS