# To encode an live webcam feed into RTMP encoded video

Tags: php, jquery, webrtc, rtmp, wowza

I am working on a concept where people can go live using their webcam. So basically it's a web app. I am using webRTC concept. My code is pretty basic but still have a look :

```
<script>
(function () {
    console.log('here');
    navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    window.hasUserMedia = function hasUserMedia() {
        return navigator.getMedia ? true : false;
    };
    var errorcallback = function (e) {
        console.log('errorCalback: ' + e);
    };
    navigator.getMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true
    },
    function (stream) {
        var video = document.getElementById('live'),
                webcamstream, streamrecorder,
                vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        console.log(video);
        video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
        //webcamstream = stream;
        //video.play();
        video.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
            var counter = 0;
            counter++;
            console.log(e);
            console.log(video.src);
        };
    }, errorcallback);
})();
```

This `video.src` gives a source but i think it's in blob format.

the output is something like `mediastream:http://localhost.movyt.com/8b57e486-a985-4331-b9ab-0eaf6def3404`.
Well blob formats can't be published. We need to encode it to RTMP encoded. 
My question is how would i encode it with out any third party softwares because as a end user i will not likely install any software for signing up a website.

I tried with flash for live streaming but there is a need to install **flash live encoder** which i don't want to use as it won't be user friendly.
There are pretty dedicated servers like wowza, dacast and all but they need RTMP encoded video streams for further processing .

note: I tried with a `<video src=video.src>` in another page but it won't fruit into any result because as per the previous code written `video.src` is coming from `video metadata`.

**So is there any way to encode my blob video to RTMP protocol?**

Comment: how about telling the reason before downvoting. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: RTMP is a flash format from 2007, so that seems like a dead end if you don't want to install flash.

Comment: can you please suggest any way using webRTC? @jib 4

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523289/sending-a-mediastream-to-host-server-with-webrtc-after-it-is-captured-by-getuser or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571044/how-to-record-webcam-and-audio-using-webrtc-and-a-server-based-peer-connection

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already looked at Wowza I assume you are going to be redistributing this published stream.  That server does have WebRTC capabilities:

https://www.wowza.com/products/capabilities/webrtc-streaming-software

You currently have to sign up for the "Preview" to activate these features, but not for much longer.

I highly recommend avoiding the attempt at using RTMP as a transport protocol to/from the browser, as this will always require a plugin like Flash (on its way out).