# Stream audio from browser to nodejs

Tags: linux, html, node.js, audio, audio-streaming

I know this is a long shot but I would like to know if this is possible and (in case of this being possible) someone to point me in the right direction.

I have a linux machine (running a nodejs server) that streams a playlist (local files) using VLC to a network.
In that network there are 10 other linux machines playing the stream sent by the server (using VLC too);

I would like to know if it is possible to develop a webapp that can transmit audio from a computer browser to the server so that it can be streamed to the other machines;

I found [this](http://blog.groupbuddies.com/posts/39-tutorial-html-audio-capture-streaming-to-node-js-no-browser-extensions) and [this](http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets) but I don't understand this quite well. Even If I can stream live audio to the server I don't know if I can "re-stream" to the other machines;

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stream recorded audio from browser to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850396/stream-recorded-audio-from-browser-to-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds doable. I went over the first [link](http://blog.groupbuddies.com/posts/39-tutorial-html-audio-capture-streaming-to-node-js-no-browser-extensions) you provided, as that is the one that can work for you. The second link is different from what you want. So as the article mentions you can configure BinaryJS on both the client and server side and set it up to upload a music file back to the server, which you can then forward to the linux machines you have set up.

Here is a link for a tutorial on how to use binaryJs to stream music to client from the server and how to upload music/video back.
http://www.olindata.com/blog/2014/01/file-uploading-and-streaming-binaryjs

If you have any further questions about the process let me know :)