# Node JS access audio interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, audio, web-audio-api

I want to send audio signal coming from my audio interface (focusrite saffire) to my nodejs server. How should I go about doing this? The easiest way would be to access the audio interface from the browser (html5) like capturing microphone output with getUserMedia (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), but couldn't find a way to access my audio interface through that library. Otherwise, I'm planning on creating a desktop application, but don't know if there is a function/library to allow access to my usb-connected audio interface.

Comment: what OS are you on ?   if linux there are a number of tools to view and change default input audio device

Comment: @ScottStensland Thanks for your reply, the OS would be linux. So after changing the default input audio device to my audio interface on the OS, I could be able to use that for the input in getUserMedia on the browser? If that's the case, I will report back once I get a hold of my audio interface.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has little to do with the Javascript or the MediaDevices API. On Linux, using Firefox, [PulseAudio is required](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/fix-common-audio-and-video-issues#w_you-may-need-to-install-the-required-pulseaudio-software) to interface with your audio hardware. Since your soundcard is an Input/Output interface, you should be able to test it pretty easily by simply playing any sound file in the browser.

Most of [PulseAudio configuration](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/) can be achieved using `pavucontrol` GUI. You should check the "configuration" tab and both "input device" & "output device" tabs to make sure your Focusrite is correctly set up and used as sound I/O.

Once this is done, you should be able to access an audio stream using the following (only available if on a "secure context", ie `localhost` or served through HTTPS, as stated in the MDN page you mentionned):

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(function(stream) {
    // do whatever you want with this audio stream
  })
```

(code snippet taken from the [MDN page about MediaDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices))

Sending audio to the server is a whole other story. Have you tried anything? Are you looking for a real-time communication with the server? If so, I'd start by having a look at the [WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API). The [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) docs might be worth reading too, but it is more oriented to client-to-client communications.

Answer (score 0):

## How to use exact device id

Use [media device constrain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#parameters) to pass exact device id.

An sample would be

```js
const preferedDeviceName = '<your_device_name>'
const deviceList = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
const audio = devices.find((device) => device.kind === 'audioinput' && device.label === preferedDeviceName)
const {deviceId} = audio;
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: { deviceId }}
```

## How to process and send to the backend

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547322/how-to-convert-getusermedia-audio-stream-into-a-blob-or-buffer)

Still not clear follow [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio?hl=pl)